# Is Nazi brutality particularly well known in the US because of the US's Jewish population?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, nazi-germany, holocaust

Related question: [Why, in the US, is Japanese brutality ignored compared with the Nazi brutality in WW2?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9561/why-in-the-us-is-japanese-brutality-ignored-compared-with-the-nazi-brutality-i)

Occasionally I come across people saying that the US's Jewish population has played a role in Nazi Germany's brutality being well known in the US compared to other historical events. This sounds plausible, but it also sounds reminiscent of claims that "the Jews" control the media.

Is Nazi Germany brutality particularly well known in the US, partially or fully, because of the US's Jewish population?

**Note:** Holocaust deniers need not answer or comment.

Comment: This would probably be better on politics.se. In any case this question could be interpreted as baiting because it is asking for opinions on an emotionally charged topic.

Comment: Yes. I recommend The Holocaust Industry by Norman Finkelstein.

Comment: Japanese committed their worst crimes on China's territory. I believe the western ignorance is due to PRC's "**bad PR**" on that matter, not due to "good PR" of others.

Comment: Is it ignored? I think it's well documented in U.S Media and literature.

Answer (score 2):

Nazi brutality is very well known because this was a singular event in 20s century Europe, with no analog (in Europe). It is well known also in England and Poland, the countries with small Jewish population. (I mean that Poland has negligible Jewish population AFTER the Holocaust). And in France and in Yugoslavia. It is also well-known and well remembered in the countries of former Soviet Union, where the remaining Jewish population was
smaller that in the US, and no sane person would say that "Jews controlled the media" in the former Soviet Union.

Comment: The “(in Europe)” bit needs to be explained a bit, I think. It's kind of the gist of the question, why does the US care more about European events than anything else? There are many reasons why Poland or England would know more about Nazi Germany in general (not only the Holocaust) that do not readily apply to the US.

Comment: The answer is very simple: US in the cultural sense is a descendant of the Western European civilization. Their language and religious and other beliefs are common with some European countries. Of course, all societies are mixed now, but what I said applies to the majority.

Comment: I am not saying the answer is not simple, I am saying it's not stated, whereas you devote quite a lot of space to unconvincing comparisons.

Comment: What about Soviet brutality? Or Mussolini fachists? This was in Europe, too.

Comment: Soviet brutality is somewhat less known because the Soviets were allies. And nothing that Mussolini fascists did stands comparison with the Holocaust.

Answer (score -2):

In a sense I suppose. Here in the states there is the freedom of speech and the free press. It is not an event that people want, particularly the Jews, to be forgotten, -and shouldn't be- in my opinion. So wouldn't it be better documented in clarity by the very victims themselves, the brutality of their captors? I wouldn't say it is a control of media but rather the utilization of the publishing medium in order to tell to the rest of the unknowing world of their experiences.